# convert arabic month name to month number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel sheet that have month name and I need to convert it to month number

I found the following way

[image]

=MONTH(DATEVALUE(A2&"1"))

but the problem that I have month names written in Arabic

so how can I solve that ?

Comment: `=MATCH(A2,{"Muharram","Safar",...},0)`  Put all twelve IN ORDER in the array.

Comment: To view or modify your language settings within Excel, go to File > Options > Language. From there, you can see what language you're currently using, add a new language, and more.

Comment: `=MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$13,0)`